# Use "subcontrollers" in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

i'm having some trouble designing an EmberJS layout. I have a view divided in two parts :

- a content library on the left
- a playlist editor on the right

Currently, those two elements share the same controller.

I can't figure how to use two different controllers for those two sides to be able to re-use the content library in other views or even having a view with two playlist editors.

My root view looks like this so far :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="playlists">
    <div id="library">{{template library}}</div>
    <div id="playlistEditor">{{template playlisteditor}}</div>
</script>
```

I saw docs about the [`{{control}}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_control) helper, but it is unstable and i'm not sure this is what i'm looking for.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer, i had to use the `{{render}}` helper, like that :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="playlists">
    <div id="library">{{render "library" library}}</div>
    <div id="playlistEditor">{{render "playlisteditor" playlist}}</div>
</script>
```

Then, in my route :

```
App.PlaylistsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
     controller.set('playlist', playlist);
     controller.set('library', library);
  }
});
```

Then, this EmberJS will automatically wire the `App.PlaylisteditorController`, the `App.LibraryController` and the views `playlisteditor` and `library`. Awesome.